# Update windows explorer shell extension with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, explorer, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have a program product which additionally installs Shell Extension to Windows Explorer. It made in C# and uses .NET Framework v4.0. Shell extension are installing by Inno Setup during installation by using regasm.exe. Everything works fine until I want to install updated version of application.  The problem is I can’t update shell extension dll because it loaded into explorer’s memory. Before installing Inno Setup shows me following message

[image]

It says installer needs to terminate Windows Explorer because it uses files which should be updated by installer.
**It terminates explorer process but doesn’t launch him again. That’s my first issue.**

Actually I don’t want to force user shutdown explorer. But I don’t know how to unload managed shell dll from explorer’s memory. If uninstall it by regasm.exe dll still remains in memory. In fact I can’t even find place where this checking occurs because I received already made installation sources.

Files-In-Use (IssProc.dll) add-in for Inno Setup doesn’t help because as soon I terminate windows explorer by this add-in, explorer immediately restarts.

How could I solve this issue? How could I update shell extension dll with better user experience?
And maybe someone could give me a hint where’s that code which checks for files in use is placed?

O and BTW I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: With the *maybe someone could give me a hint where’s that code which checks for files in use is placed* you meant in InnoSetup source code ? Or you meant to show the example script of how to use the solution ?

Comment: I meant in Inno Setup source code. I can’t find anything similar to specified above files validation. We have only checking for .NET v4 in Inno Setup. Probably this check made by Inno Setup engine?

Comment: I see this check made by Setup Wizard

Comment: It's in the `Wizard.pas`, the `TWizardForm.QueryRestartManager` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`restartreplace`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm) flag at your file entry. From the reference:

> When an existing file needs to be replaced, and it is in use (locked)
>   by another running process, Setup will by default display an error
>   message. ***This flag tells Setup to instead register the file to be
>   replaced the next time the system is restarted*** (by calling MoveFileEx
>   or by creating an entry in WININIT.INI). When this happens, ***the user
>   will be prompted to restart their computer at the end of the
>   installation process.***

So using this flag won't cause the wizard to ask to terminate applications using the file but schedule the file update to the next reboot and prompt user to restart the computer at the installation end, what is in my opinion quite user friendly and commonly used.

Comment: Thx. Works like a Swiss clock.

Comment: IIRC, it will still give the RestartManager prompt, but then go on to replace on a restart if it's still in use. You'll need to adjust the filter for that.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the prompt , you should set "CloseApplications=no" in the [Setup] simply .
But you still need use the restartplace  flag in the [File] if your are sure the replacement is necessary but later.

Comment: That will effectively do the same as `restartreplace`.

Comment: I hoped they were ,so I can solve the same  issue by this way directly, but bad luck they were not by my test . I had to spend  more hours to do more try . :(  I did it by the latest Inno setup 5.5.5(a).